# Send Aurelia Error logs to server and notify the user

Tags: logging, ecmascript-6, aurelia

I would like to know how to access Aurelia logger, catch the errors only and trigger a function that send that data to some server. 
Also I have to trigger Alert box, to inform the User that some error occur.
That need to works for my entire App.

So far, I found that I can get logs from LogManager:

`import {LogManager} from 'aurelia-framework';` in main.js,

but I don't know how to access it and create a custom logger that will send that error data. 
If someone know from where I can find more info about that LogManager and how interact with it, that will be helpful as well.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to write a custom logger to do what you want. It's fairly simple. Just use the `ConsoleAppender` as a starting point: https://github.com/aurelia/logging-console/blob/master/src/index.js

Then you'll need to register it with Aurelia at startup. This is done with the following code:

```
import {LogManager} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {CustomAppender} from './your-custom-code;

LogManager.addAppender(new CustomAppender());
LogManager.setLevel(LogManager.logLevel.debug);

export function configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .defaultBindingLanguage()
    .defaultResources()
    .history()
    .router()
    .eventAggregator();

  aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot('app', document.body));
}
```

This is in our docs (though admittedly, we can improve searching for this) here: http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.2.4/doc/article/cheat-sheet just Ctrl-F for LogManager.

Comment: I did a custom Appender, but how to test if it is working. When I try to produce some error, it hits aurelia-pal.js and I have nothing in a logger? 
Or for example if there is error with some request it hits aurelia-fetch-client.js. 

How to catch that kind of errors and is it possible to use LogManager for those?

Comment: Hi @Ashley Grant. I have I question. I'm new in Aurelia world. I have created Logger.js (copy of index.js) in the same directory as main.ts. I try to import logger as:  import {CustomAppender} from './logger.js';  and I get error: "Cannot find module './logger"   What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You probably don't need the .js at the end of the file name. Let me know if that helps

Comment: ok, half of my problem was missing import {LogManager} from 'aurelia-framework';  , but I still don't have consoleAppender :/

Comment: Ok, I have solution. index.js is written is ts, and should have been named: index.ts  @AshleyGrant

Comment: Today I will make pull request with my working files to github repo.

Comment: Hi @AshleyGrant If I add more methods to the custom appender code why is it not accessible? If I had a log_err_to_backend() method along with error, warn, info, etc, I cannot say logger.log_err_to_backend() in any view model. See my s/o here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41448108/how-to-extend-the-aurelia-logger-with-additional-methods

Answer (score -1):

[here](http://blog.williamhayes.org/2015/08/logging-in-aurelia-2.html)'s a good example. You have to have your custom class in addition to LogManager.